# grep status and loop it until the count condition in shell

Tags: shell, scripting, grep

I would to check the status and if the status is not "Running" would like my script to sleep for 5 seconds and increase the counter.

Status of cell can be checked using mcstat

```
14:24:25 # mcstat -n cell1
XXX Impact InfoStatus 9.5.00 (Build 241196604 - 15-Jan-2014) [l2]
Copyright 1998-2014 XXX Software, Inc. as an unpublished work.  All rights reserved.
Running
```

I am interested in extracting "Running"

Draft copy of my script

```
count=0
checker="false"

#take a nap before you work
sleep 2m

#grep for status string Running
status=`mcstat -n cell1| grep "Running"`


#lets count for 10 & keep checking for status
while [ $count -le 10 ]
do
    if [ ("$status" == "Running") ]; then
        checker=true
    else
        sleep 5s
        echo " waiting $count"
    fi
done
```

Question:
1. How can i use grep command to find the string "Running" by running mcstat command and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
status=`mcstat -n cellname | grep Running`
```

Edit: notice those aren't apostrophes, they are the one on the same key as ~

alternatively you could do:

```
status=`mcstat -n cellname | tail -1`
```

Edit: try this:

```
while [ $count -le 10 ]
do
    status=`mcstat -n cell1 | tail -1`

    if [ "$status" == "Running" ]; then
        checker=true
        break
    else
        sleep 5s
        echo " waiting $count"
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
done
```

See this tutorial for more on if/else, I think that's where your problem is:
http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php

Comment: yes, but if my grep doesn't find "Running" it would throw an error.

Comment: it shouldn't throw an error, it should just return a blank string.  Also you can use the tail option.

Comment: oh, also, do the status= check inside the do, otherwise you only check the first time...

Comment: 15:17:15 # . ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `"$status"'
-bash: ./test.sh: line 14: `    if [ ("$status" == "Running") ]; then'                                                                               i thought "$status" nothing but the string value, isn't it ?

Comment: I updated my answer to show the whole thing, i think your problem is on the if/else with the () in there.